# date picker is not working on spring form:input

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datepicker

I am using spring form in my web page.

So for simple 
`<input type=text class="datepicker-1">`

we are using `<form:input path="" class="datepicker-1"/>`

But while i am applying datepicker through `JQUERY` syntax in js file

```
  $(function(){
     $(".datepicker-1").datepicker();     
  });
```

Here for simple input html tag the calender is coming but for spring input tag the calender is not coming.

can anyone suggest me please.

Comment: Have you included jqueryUI in your page? The `datepicker` is not a part of standard jQuery.

Comment: Look at generated html code for `<form:input>`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have include all the necessary js files, yes input id value is generating same as simple html input tag. but calender drop up is not comming.

Comment: @student-17 : `<form:input path="" cssClass="datepicker-1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`cssClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)** instead of **`class`**

```
<form:input path="" cssClass="datepicker-1"/>
```

Also check that you are included jQuery and jQuery-ui library in your html page

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker-1").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class="datepicker-1">
```

Comment: either way css is applying. but the calender drop up is not apearing. same for  simple input html tag is working.

Comment: are you included jQuery library and jquery-ui library with it's css file

Comment: yes the snipped code you have added for simple input element it is working same as this. but not for spring input element.

I have added
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: please check that rendering output source in your  browser

Comment: in source code the spring input and html input are exactly same.
1. this is spring form source :

`<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Date To" class="datepicker-1 pp_text hasDatepicker" name="dateTo" id="dp1432717151369">`               

2. html input which is working : 
`<input type="text" class="datepicker-1 pp_text hasDatepicker" id="dp1432717151370">`